# Finding change in enthalpy for a reaction with an atom in elemental state using bond energy

Tags: thermodynamics, bond, enthalpy

For example, consider $\ce{C(s) + O2(g) -> CO2(g)}$.

If we know the bond energies for $\ce{O=O}$ and $\ce{C=O}$, can we determine $\Delta H$, even though there is carbon in the reaction? Can we ignore it, or is there a certain way to compute the energy?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things we need to note with this. For one, you need to know the bond *enthalpies* if you are going to obtain $\Delta H$, not the bond energies. Second, we can't just use the bond enthalpies in this case because that would ignore that we have $C(s)$ when we need $C(g)$ to make this reaction occur. We have to explicitly include the atomization energy of carbon (the energy needed to break graphite into single carbon atoms).

[image: thermodynamic cycle]